# Reset arraylist object property for all objects

Tags: java, arraylist, operations

I'm having an arraylist which contains object of class X. Class x has property name & desc. When I pass this object to a method, it needs to set all class object(X) description as 'MyDescription'. What is the best way to do it.

For eg

```
class X{
    String name;
    String desc="Hello";
    //We have getters & setters too.
}

ArrayList<X> obj=getArraylist();
```

Now we got say 10 object of class X in obj. I need to reset all its description to 'MyDescription'
Can I do without looping into each object and reset its value? Please suggest.

Comment: No, you cannot accomplish that without iterating over the list.

Comment: I need more thoughts,<BR> As string is immutable, can we do something.

Comment: How would you expect to be able to do this without iterating over the list?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this without looping of some form.

The best way to accomplish this is to iterate of the list and set the values as needed.

Comment: If we use something else than arraylist, Can we do this. Trying to avoid iteration.

Comment: The very idea of performing an action on each object is iteration. What could you possibly be looking for?

Comment: Why are you so against iteration? It is a basic fundamental of programming. There is a reason it exists and so many people use it.